# Better msg implementation for random, complicated shape in 2D

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, message, geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to design a `.msg` that represents a line with irregular shape. What would be the best optimal option especially utilizing existing `ROS` msg types as much as possible? Example image:

[image description http://www.had2know.com/images/irregshap.jpg](http://www.had2know.com/images/irregshap.jpg)(Image obtained from http://www.had2know.com/images/irregshap.jpg)

The line like red curvy one in this figure is my target. For now, whether the line draws a cycle can be ignored for my purpose (to represent non-cyclic line is another design discussion).

My idea is:

```
geometry_msgs/Point[] dotsOnLine
# The order of Point objects in the array can be determined by certain algorithm. Not a focus in this discussion.
```

I found [`sensor_msgs/RegionOfInterest`](http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/RegionOfInterest.html) might be a good fit for rectangular/squares, but I guess not for irregular shapes. I'm asking particularly because I'm afraid I might be missing good existing `msg` types (I've only looked at `common_msgs`).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36009/better-msg-implementation-for-random,-complicated-shape-in-2d/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd say this is exactly what you are looking for: [geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PolygonStamped.html). That contains a standard header as well as a `geometry_msgs/Polygon` message that is basically the same as yours (but uses 32-bit floats instead of 64-bit doubles).

A bonus to using `geometry_msgs/PolygonStamped` instead of the non-stamped version or your own message is that you get the [RVIZ Polygon display](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Polygon) for free :-)

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-06-08**:
+1; sounds perfect incl. RViz feature except that I'm not yet sure how the msg type works when the line doesn't go cyclic which I'm trying to figure out now. Also I need to know how sparse the points can become so that ROS detects the line closes its loop.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-06-08**:
Take a look at http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Polygon.html (the embedded Polygon message). It states that the assumption is that the first and last points are connected, so it can't represent non-closed polygons. I don't think there are any sparseness constraints...

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2012-06-11**:
Yeah I saw that doc too, & I just tested with a simple code out of curiosity (e.g. what error would I get if loop not closed etc.). Turned out to me that `ROS` compensates the miss-match b/w 2 pts so that the line represented by PolygonStamped always closed-loops. My sample code: http://goo.gl/FKlXX